# Converting Excel values from 24h to 12h

Tags: excel, excel-formula, time

I have a series of times I need to convert, currently they're in two columns (J & K) and I need them to be in a single column, as 12 hour times

eg:

| Column J | Column K |
| --- | --- |
| 1403 | 1430 |
| 855 | 1000 |

And I need them in the format of

| Column J | Column K | Column L |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1403 | 1430 | 02:03 PM - 02:30 PM |
| 855 | 1000 | 08:55 AM - 10:00 AM |

I've tried a dozen different methods and the best I can do is convert the columns just to variations of 12am

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46594757/how-do-i-format-cells-to-display-a-time-range-instead-of-just-the-time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following formula in cell L2 and copy down as required:

```
=TEXT(TIME(LEFT(J2,LEN(J2)-2),RIGHT(J2,2),0),"hh:mm AM/PM") & " - " &TEXT(TIME(LEFT(K2,LEN(K2)-2),RIGHT(K2,2),0),"hh:mm AM/PM")
```

[image: POC]

NOTE:  While this may look pretty it actually makes the time harder to work with since its now stored as text.  You will need to strip the time from the text any time you need to work with it.  I would recommend storing the time as a number, using three columns, and applying a custom format to the time column.  Below is an example:

[image]

Comment: You're a perfect man Ed, I managed to scrape out converting them to an actual time value using =TIME(LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2),RIGHT(A1,2),0) and then coverting to 12h, but this does it all.

Comment: Regarding your edit, wasn't actually an issue because I'm saving the file as a CSV for importing into another platform, also made it super easy to a Find/Replace on all the bad values (not all rows had times and needed to be left blank)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative approach using <kbd>TEXT( )</kbd> Function.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L2</kbd>

```
=TEXT(
    TEXT(J2, "00\:00"),
    "hh:mm AM/PM"
) & " - " &
    TEXT(
        TEXT(K2, "00\:00"),
        "hh:mm AM/PM"
    )
```

---

Or, Using <kbd>TEXTJOIN( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>L2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(
    " - ",
    ,
    TEXT(
        TEXT(J2:K2, "00\:00"),
        "hh:mm AM/PM"
    )
)
```

---